# Android - creating a dialog with an image seems to put a black bar on top of the dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I create a Dialog like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.please_wait); 
dialog.show(); //this will show dialog
```

and here is the xml for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/please_wait"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/please_wait_1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the image renders, but it also puts a black bar on top of the image that I didn't want. Is that common? And how do I get rid of the black bar?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds strange, can you post a screenshot of the dialog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the image you are using is too small to scale. Have you tried adding the following attribute to the ImageView element of your xml?

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```